# DB2/400 : difference between BLOB abd GRAPHIC DB2/400 property?

Tags: db2-400

Can somebody can explain me what's the difference between **BLOB** and **GRAPHIC** DB2/400 database property ?

Answer (score 0):

`BLOB` is a large object data type, and `GRAPHIC` is a double byte character data type The large object version of `GRAPHIC` is `DBCLOB`. Double byte characters are a pre-unicode construct to encode languages with a large number of symbols. They are still used in EBCDIC systems like IBM i, though Unicode support is improving there.